# Show that if four distinct integers are chosen between $1$ and $60$ inclusive, some two of them must differ by at most $19$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I am trying to understand this question. This is from the book Essential Discrete Mathematics for Computer Science and Question is from Chapter one "the pigeonhole principle" So clearly we have to prove using pigeonhole principle

But lets say I choose the numbers $1, 2, 3,$ and $60$ these numbers are clearly within $1$ and $60$ inclusive but no two numbers differ by at most $19$. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, since $\ 2-1=3-2=1\ $, and $\ 3-1=2\ $ there are *three pairs* of your numbers that differ by *much less than* $19$, and hence also by *at most* $19$.

Let $\ a,b,c,d\ $ be four distinct numbers between $1$ and $60$ arranged in increasing order:$\ a<b<c<d\ $. Then, since $\ d\le60\ $ and $\ a\ge1\ $, we must have $\ d-a\le59\ $.  Let $\ m=\min(b-a,c-b,d-c)\ $.  Then
\begin{align}
b-a&\ge m\ ,\\
c-b&\ge m\ \text{, and}\\
d-c&\ge m\ .
\end{align}
If we add these inequalities, we get $\ 59\ge d-a\ge3m\ $, which gives $\ m\le\frac{59}{3}<20\ $, and since $\ m\ $ must be an integer, it can be at most $\ 19\ $.  It follows that at least one of the pairs $\ \{a,b\}, \{b,c\},\ $ and $\ \{c,d\}\ $ of numbers differs by at most $\ 19\ $.

Comment: lonza leggiera thanks for the brilliant explanation.